# How stop Video player when navigate(push) other screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-video-player, flutter-routes

How to stop the video player when switching to another screen. I have a player and when I move across another screen the video doesn't stop and keeps running because it's still on the stack. I can't **_chewieController.pause();** because my widget is in other space I cannot use the player controller there.How to stop it(I can't do Navigator.pop() because need navigate back when user want)?

Comment: can you include sample code snippet that will reproduce the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

When everything seems to fail, just create a global variable to be used as a flag for things like this, that can stop your player, whenever you click on an action that leaves the view.

Comment: Thanks for answer if I don't find other solution I will do like that)